# Подключение к БД Mysql, получение данных

Tags: c#

Как можно осуществить подключение к базе данных Mysql и осуществить запросы?
К примеру в PHP я подключаюсь так

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "table";
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
```

И потом делаю запрос на получении информации по ID

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Id` = '"$id"'");
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

А потом использую так

```
$email = $user["Email"];
$name = $user["Name"];
```

В интернете не могу найти понятное подключение и получение информации, как в PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для подключения к MySql на C# используйте к примеру библиотеку **MySql.Data** (*MySql Connector/NET*).

---

### Пример

Добавьте пространство имен

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

Затем создайте строку подключения при помощи класса `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder stringBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

stringBuilder.Server = "localhost";
stringBuilder.UserID = "root";
stringBuilder.Password = "";
stringBuilder.Database = "table";

string connectionString = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

После чего создайте подключение к MySql.

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Создайте команду и установите SQL запрос.

```
uint id = 0;

MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = @id";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id); // Заметьте, можно использовать параметры.
```

Откройте подключение, вызовите `MySqlDataReader` и считывайте результат.

```
connection.Open();

string name = null;
string email = null;

using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) // reader.Read() возвращает true и переходит к следующему ряду.
    {
        name = reader.GetString("Name");
        email = reader.GetString("Email");
    }
}

connection.Close();
```